# Searching a JSON array deserialized to a dynamic object type

Tags: c#

I have an array from my frontend I send to the backend serialized to JSON. I am trying to bulk import some box ids into my database as we only store file path so I am going to do the comparison on that. The JSON data from the front end is of this type:

```
[{"File Type" : "Folder", "File Id" : "dfasf23r", "File Path" : "/dir/test/filename.docx"}, ...etc]
```

I use the following to deserialize it:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> BoxIdsImport([FromForm] string jsonData)
    {

        dynamic json = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonData);

        String query = "select FILE_ID, (DOCUMENT_PATH + DOCUMENT_FILENAME) as FULL_PATH, BoxID from dbo.DocumentTBL";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringSandbox))
        {
            var queryResult = await connection.QueryAsync(query);

            foreach(var item in queryResult)
            {
                //This is where I am trying to do the search to find the match file path in the json data then take the associated box id and I will store back to my table which I will later send to my DB
                if(item.FULL_PATH == matched value)
                {
                   item.BoxID = the associated box id for the matched record
                }
            }
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

How can I search the JSON variable for a match and if so take that index or the BoxId from that row?

Comment: Maybe deserialize it into a list of actual objects then put it in a dictionary for easy lookup

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using `dynamic` would be using an array of objects. The advantage is that the deserialized model can be used for LINQ queries and is type safe.

```
public class MyItemClass
{
    [JsonProperty("File Type")]
    public string FileType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("File Path")]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    // ... and so on
}
```

then to deserialize:

```
MyItemClass[] data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyItemClass[]>(jsonData);
```

and search the array with LINQ:

```
var fileFound = data.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FilePath == item.FULL_PATH);
```

Comment: Could you extend this to include the LINQ query. I rarely do LINQ but am open to it.

Comment: The answer is updated.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can cast the `dynamic` to an `IDictionary<string, object>` and use it like a dictionary.

```cs
var json = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonData);
var dict = json as IDictionary<string, object>;
Console.Write(dict["File Path"])
```

Since you have an array of dictionaries essentially, you can deserialize the JSON this way:

```cs
var json = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>[]>(jsonData);
foreach (var dict in json) { 
    Console.Write(dict["File Path"]);
}
```

2. You could use the Json.NET package and parse with a [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jobject.htm) This gives you the advantage of being able to parse a complex object with many sub-objects and traverse the entire tree regardless of data types.

```cs
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
Console.Write("{0} = {1}", obj.Key, obj.Value);
```

3. If you can control the deserialization, I would suggest actually defining a type and deserializing to a known type with known json values - same as the example in the answer from @martin-staufcik

```cs
var myObj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(jsonData);
Console.Write(myObj.FileId);
```

Comment: I like approach 1 as I am not trying to build out a model for this (ultimately I can but trying to do without) but how do you know the file path is the dictionary key? I dont see where you define that your piece of code.

Comment: @IrishRedneck I've updated the answer with an example that should make it more clear how getting your array of JSON objects into `Dictionary`s would work